# How can I return a Unicode escaped string to an HTTP client via an http-inbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a simple http-inbound-gateway that calls a service-activator and returns the result to the HTTP client.

The service-activator returns a String containing Unicode escape sequences, like this:

```
Fran\u00e7ais
```

This is passed to the http-inbound-gateway to be returned to the client as a response payload.

When I call the inbound gateway's URL, however, there seems to be some conversion going on; the escape sequences are rendered into their binary format which my browser cannot render:

```
Fran�ais
```

I would like the escape sequences to be passed through the inbound-http-gateway and returned to the browser.

What I should be doing to achieve that result?

Here is the relevant SI config:

```
<http:inbound-gateway
    id="inboundGateway"
    request-channel="inboundClientRequestChannel"
    request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-channel="inboundClientResponseChannel"
    reply-timeout="30000"
    supported-methods="GET"
    message-converters="stringJsonMessageConverter"
    path="/test">

    <http:request-mapping produces="application/json"/>

</http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="inboundClientRequestChannel"
    output-channel="inboundClientResponseChannel"
    ref="clientRequestHandler"/>

<bean id="stringJsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <value>application/json</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that the `stringJsonMessageConverter`, an instance of `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter`, by default converts Strings to the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

See the Javadoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html). Note the defaultCharset constructor parameter.

Initializing stringJsonMessageConverter to use the UTF-8 encoding solved the problem.

Comment: Not for 2 days. I'll do it then ;)